# SQL delete almost identical rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a table that have 5 columns, and instead of update, I've done insert of all rows(stupid mistake). How to get rid of duplicated records. They are identical except of the id. I can't remove all records, but I want do delete half of them.

ex. table:

```
+-----+-------+--------+-------+
| id  | name  | name2  | user  |
+-----+-------+--------+-------+
|   1 | nameA | name2A | u1    |
|  12 | nameA | name2A | u1    |
|   2 | nameB | name2B | u2    |
| 192 | nameB | name2B | u2    |
+-----+-------+--------+-------+
```

How to do this?
I'm using Microsoft Sql Server.

Comment: I think you can find your solution here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try:

```
with c as
(
    select 
        *, row_number() over(partition by name, name2, [user] order by id) as n
    from YourTable
)
delete from c
where n > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
    DELETE
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name, Name2, User)
```

That is untested so may need adapting. The following video will provide you with some more information about this query.

[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioDJ0xVOHDY)

Comment: I would use MIN instead of MAX (so that the presumably old records are saved), and i would suggest that the OP adds _all_ other relevant columns (if there are any) to the group by to avoid false positives. But this solution should work

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing that out. MIN would be better over MAX

Answer (score 0):

This is more specific query than @TechDo as I find duplicates where name, name2 and user are identical not only name.

```
with duplicates as
(
    select t.id, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.name, t.name2, t.[user] order by t.id) as RowNumber
    from YourTable t
)

delete duplicates 
where RowNumber > 1
```

**SQLFiddle demo to try it yourself: [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bed0/1)**